# get Facebook PostID from Photo for API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

To analyse a post I need to enter the PostID in this box:
[image]

The PostID can be found in the Facebook Link in the following Format:

> https://www.facebook.com/**pagename**/posts/**postID**

I have tested this and it works fine. However I would like to do the same thing on a Photo post, rather than a Status.

But Photo posts are in this form:

> https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?**fbid**=.......&**set**=.......&**type**=......&**theater**

I'm assumed **fbid** was the correct ID, since the length of the String is identical to that of PostID. So I copied and pasted that into the `GET` request in the API.

But I get the following error

[image]

Any idea what the correct ID to use is?

Comment: You should not try and get any IDs from URLs in the first place. Read the `/feed`, `/posts` or `/photos` edges for the respective user/page instead, then you will get the proper IDs in the first place.

Comment: Could you expand on that?... i need some ID to use the API, how would I get it? Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

The only photos you can get with `public_profile` permission are Facebook fan page photos. The reason why you are getting the error is either you are trying to access a photo from the session user without `user_photos` or you are trying to access a photo from another profile (which will not work, unless that user has granted the app both `user_friends` and `user_photos`, yes, the profile and the session user need to be friends)

Comment: Here is a sample photo from a fan page:   https://www.facebook.com/susnepal/posts/1043102282399851?comment_id=928668780542188&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R9%22%7D  ... I used the ID - 1043102282399851 and get same error

Comment: @GregPeckory That is a **person** not a fanpage.